# Waterfall in NodeJs appears to be asynchronous. Why?

Tags: node.js

I am running a waterfall for every configuration file in a loop. In the very first function of the waterfall I am downloading a file from the SFTP. From what I read about waterfall it is supposed to wait until one function finishes before it starts the next one.

What is happening to me is the exact opposite.

Calling the waterfall function for every config file in a loop:

```
for (var i=0; i<configFiles.length; i++) {
  waterfallMain(configFiles[i],i);
}
```

The waterfall function:

```
function waterfallMain(configFile, i) {
  async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
      // If there is no such file error is thrown and next iteration of the loop starts
      util.log("Downloading config files."+i);
      sftpHandler.downloadFile(credentials.sftpPathToImportFiles+configFile.importFileName, callback);
                },
    function(callback) {
      // Change file encoding to UTF8
      util.log("Going to change file name of the file on SFTP prepending in_progress.");
      sftpHandler.renameFileOnSftp();
    },
    function(callback) {
      // Change file encoding to UTF8
      util.log("Going to change file encoding to UTF8.");
      readFileSync_encoding(configFile.importFileName, "ISO-8859-1", callback);
    },
    function(fileData, callback) {
      util.log("Parsing the file data.");
        parseFileData(fileData, configFile, callback);
    }],
    // the bonus final callback function
    function(err, status) {
      if (err) {
        // app has crashed
        util.log(err);
        return;
      }
      // keep looping with 1 min delay
      util.log(status);
      setTimeout(function() {
        mainProcess();
      }, 60000);
      return;
    });
 }
```

And the `downloadFile` function:

```
SftpHandler.prototype.downloadFile = function (path, callback) {
    // Download swush file from SFTP
   client.scp({
      'host': this.host,
      'username': this.username,
      'password': this.password,
      'path': path
      },'./', function(err) {
        if (err) {
          return callback("File: "+path+" "+err);
        } else {
          return callback(null);
        }
      });
};
```

And the output:

```
29 Jul 11:58:01 - Main process started.
29 Jul 11:58:01 - Running through all config files. Count: 3
29 Jul 11:58:01 - Downloading config files.0
29 Jul 11:58:01 - Downloading config files.1
29 Jul 11:58:01 - Downloading config files.2
29 Jul 11:58:02 - File: /E-drive/sftp/VismaReports/Test/QueueSystem/test2.csv Er
ror: file does not exist
29 Jul 11:58:03 - File: /E-drive/sftp/VismaReports/Test/QueueSystem/test5.csv Er
ror: file does not exist
29 Jul 11:58:03 - Going to change file name of the file on SFTP prepending in_pr
ogress.
```

I wouldn't expect to see `Downloading config files.+i` to see there 3 times before the actual download has happened. This seems to me it's asynchronous where I wouldn't expect it to be.

Comment: You have a misunderstanding of what async.js does. IT IS NOT POSSIBLE TO CONVERT ASYNCHRONOUS FUNCTIONS INTO SYNCHRONOUS. IT IS NOT POSSIBLE TO WAIT. What you can do instead is manage the flow of what functions gets called when. That is why you pass the array of functions to waterfall to allow it to execute them sequentially. However, if you call a second waterfall then both waterfall processes will execute in parallel (inside each they are sequential as would be expected)

Comment: On the margin - I recommend to always prefer Promises over `async.waterfall` (in fact, Bluebird eliminates need for 90% of `async` module). See [Bluebird promisification](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promisification.html) for further details.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i=0; i<configFiles.length;i++){
        waterfallMain(configFiles[i],i);
}
```

You run async code as sync. Try like below

```
async.eachSeries(configFiles, waterfallMain, function(err) { // sequence run 
    console.log((err) ? err.message : 'Done')}; 

    // Process error here
})
...
function waterfallMain(configFile, callback){
    async.waterfall([
            function(callback){
                util.log("Downloading config files.", configFiles);
                sftpHandler.downloadFile(credentials.sftpPathToImportFiles+configFile.importFileName, callback);
            },
            function(callback) {
                util.log("Going to change file name of the file on SFTP prepending in_progress.");
                sftpHandler.renameFileOnSftp(callback); // !!! You must call callback function to move next 
            },
            function(callback) {
                util.log("Going to change file encoding to UTF8.");
                readFileSync_encoding(configFile.importFileName, "ISO-8859-1", callback); // !!! Smth wrong readFileSync_encoding like sync-function. Why it call callback? 
            },
            function(fileData, callback) {
                util.log("Parsing the file data.");
                parseFileData(fileData, configFile, callback);
            }],
            callback // !!! simple call callback. Errors processing above.
/* This function is not good
        // the bonus final callback function
        function(err, status) {  // !!! what is status? Where it's set?
            // app has crashed
            if (err) 
                return util.log(err); // !!! shortly

            // !!! WTF?!
            // keep looping with 1 min delay
            util.log(status);
            setTimeout(function(){
                mainProcess();
            }, 60000);
        }
*/      
        );
}
```